# Creating a function to generate other code on the fly

Tags: javascript

I have this code which modifies the text (generated by a jquery validator plugin ) associated with labels of required form elements when they are valid:

```
 var phrases = Array('OK!', 'Sweet!', 'Nice!', 'On a roll!', 'Thanks!', 'Perfect!', 'You amaze me!');

 var election_date_phrase = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)] ;
 var another_element_phrase = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)] ;
 // and so on for each element

 $('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'em#election_date_ul_form-error', function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('valid') && $(this).text() === 'Ok!') {
     var phrase = election_date_phrase;
     $(this).text(phrase);
   }
 });

 $('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'em#another_element_ul_form-error', function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('valid') && $(this).text() === 'Ok!') {
     var phrase = another_element_phrase;
     $(this).text(phrase);
   }
 });
 // and so on for each element
```

Obviously, this code is repetitive and I'm sure it can be factored down. Not being very experienced with javascript, I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to do this.

**Failed attempt #1**
I feel like I might be close but the `DOMSubTreeModified` is not getting triggered (probably because it's wrapped in a function.

```
  var valid_phrase_changer = (function (element) {
      alert(element);
    var phrases = Array('OK!', 'Sweet!', 'Nice!', 'On a roll!', 'Thanks!', 'Perfect!', 'You amaze me!');
    var phrase = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)] ;
    return function (element, phrase) {
      $('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'em#' + element + '-error', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('valid') && $(this).text() === 'Ok!') {
          $(this).text(phrase);
        }
      });
    };
  });

  valid_phrase_changer('election_desc_ul_form');
```

Note, the phrase has to be static for each element. I want it to be the same for each individual element.

Comment: You are looking for closures.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's the word I was looking for but couldn't remember. I'll google that.

Comment: Just stick all the common code in a function, and pass in the different parts.

Comment: Yeah, I went in that direction but the function has to know which element was triggered so I don't think that will work.

Comment: Pass `this` inside that function as an argument

Comment: You could also put the `phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)]` inside the function instead of defining `election_date_phrase`, `another_element_phrase`, etc ahead of time.

Comment: Made an answer, but I neglected the `this` part. I haven't used JS in awhile and don't want to confuse `this` usage. Should be able to just pass `this` in though.

Comment: Yeah, but I want this to be triggered only on certain elements, not all of them. So I need a unique `$('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified` for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, finally. Trick was to use a `forEach` loop to create the code for each element. I think the big part of my problem is I'm still not familiar with js/jQuery syntax and keep forgetting that `on` is nothing but a function call with three arguments with and that the third argument a closure.

```
 var phrases = Array('OK!', 'Sweet!', 'Nice!', 'On a roll!', 'Thanks!', 'Perfect!', 'You amaze me!');

 function valid_phrase_changer(elements) {
   elements.forEach(function(element) {
     var phrase = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)] ;
     $('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'em#' + element + '-error', function () {
       if ($(this).hasClass('valid') && $(this).text() === 'Ok!') {
         $(this).text(phrase);
       }
     });
   });
 }

 valid_phrase_changer(['election_desc_ul_form', 'election_date_ul_form']);
```